# Wicket: Cannot read property 'Ajax' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

I have a page in Wicket that throws a javascript error because it doesn't load Wicket library on client side. I don't know why. The generated client code is as follows:

```
        Wicket.Event.add(window, "domready", function(event) { 
        Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"./web.TaskPage?4-1.0-modal~javascript~error~close","c":"modal_javascript_error_close5","e":"click"});
    .
    . (more code)
    . 
}
```

On server side i have, for example, a link button:

```
public static Component createCloseBt() {
    AjaxLink<String> modalCloseBt = new AjaxLink<String>("modal-javascript-error-close") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            IRSPage.closeModal(target);
        }
    };
    return modalCloseBt;
}
```

The error that i am getting is:

> web.TaskPage?4:148 Uncaught TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'Ajax' of undefined
>       at HTMLDocument. (web.TaskPage?4:148)
>       at fire (jquery-1.12.4-ver-1494329056398.js:3232)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4-ver-1494329056398.js:3362)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4-ver-1494329056398.js:3582)
>       at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4-ver-1494329056398.js:3617)

What should i check? Why in that point i don't have Wicket.Ajax.ajax ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I see is if you use FilteringHeaderResponse in YourApplication.java.

FilteringHeaderResponse is used when you want to put your JavaScript files in the bottom of the HTML of the page (just before the `</body>`. If you filter out the JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItems but you don't filter out also OnDomReadyHeaderItem/OnLoadHeaderItem/OnEventHeaderItem then this may happen.

Comment: Thank's for the response, but I don't have a FilteringHeaderResponse in my application.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce it in a mini demo application then please attach it to a ticket in Wicket's JIRA!

Comment: Ok. I'll try. Another pages works well so I am confused. I am migrating an application from wicket 1.5.5 to 8. So, i have to verified a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem. It was a behavior component that added javascript code that overrided the Wicket object. That was needed for 1.5.5 version but not now.